# Localization issue : it always displays in French

Tags: ios7, xcode6, localizable.strings

I localize my strings with `localizable.strings` for `Base` and `French` where the base version is in english.

Project info :

[image]

Project navigator :

[image]

IT WORKS PERFECTLY ON iOS8 !

But on iOS7, I always have the french version, no matter the iPhone langage I set.

Why ?

Comment: do you have an iOS 7 device or is this the iOS 7 simulator?

Comment: I have an iOS7 device

Comment: I've just edited the question.

Comment: Besides changing the language on your iOS 7 device, did you also change the region?

Comment: No I haven't, but in spite of that, the other apps did change their langage. Facebook for example.

Comment: Do you try delete BASE and add English locale file ? I have English and Spanish in my apps, but I don't have BASE file.